# Mailchip Edit Template - Coding Link into editable Content

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

So I am trying to edit a purchased Mailchimp e-mail template. This one is created to be edited in the "design" function, however I am trying to edit the code. I have a basic understanding of code but I am having an issue editing this piece below. It says that the image is "editable" so whenever I try to use  it spits out gibberish. What can I do to insert the link? (Also I know I'm using incorrect wording, so I apologize.)

```html
</td>
<td style="line-height: 0px;" align="center">
    <img editable="" label="3" data-crop="false" style="display:block; line-height:0px; font-size:0px; border:0px;" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/629323fec37da7c4397c47010/images/d91c364d-8050-40b1-a7a3-fbf3f0ca2c72.png" width="12" height="12" alt="img" mc:edit="3">
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "try to use it"? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: So whenever I try to use <a href="url">link text</a> it changes the design to coding instead of making the element (image) clickable to a link

Comment: So you're trying to replace the <img> tag with a link tag? Or you're trying to wrap the img tag in a link?